# How do you run a tkinker and a discord bot code at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter, events

Hi Im creating a discord bot for a a server and i wanted to make a little GUI to check if my bot is doing is job but the `client.run(token)` of my bot block the tkinker code and the `root.mainloop()` of tkinker block the bot code .

So do you have any idea to make it work or is it never gonna work ?

I have already tried `root.after()` but it didn't worked or i used it wrong.

So do you have any idea to make it work or is it never gonna work ?

Comment: Multithreading? Move the bot to a child thread and run the tkinter app on the main thread (tkinter must always run on the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that those calls never return.  The easiest approach would be to spawn one or both of those calls in a thread so that they can run forever without blocking the other from running.  The standard library's [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module is a good place to start.

Comment: can you explain how to use it i don't understand